# a few, several, and many before hundred / hundreds of

Tags: determiners, numbers

Please examine the following phrases:

1. a few hundred books
2. a few hundreds of books
3. several hundred books
4. several hundreds of books
5. many hundred books
6. many hundreds of books

I think #1, #3, and #6 are correct. What about the others?
Also, it seems to me (although I'm by no means certain) that "many" patterns differently from "a few" and "several." If that's the case, do you have an explanation?

Comment: I don't think that thread touches upon "many hundreds of" or "many hundred."

Comment: All are fine, although the plural "hundreds" is not common.  The duplicate question definitely addresses this, if you read all the answer choices.

Comment: @Andrew: I think the plural "hundreds" was more common centuries ago than it is today, but it also seems to me that if we *do* encounter it today, it's most likely to be in contexts where the intention is to ***emphasise*** the fact that that (say) something costs ***a few** hundreds of dollars* (rather than ***thousands***), or weighs ***many** hundreds of tons* (rather than ***many tens/ dozens***, or just a few hundreds, but not as much as a thousand).